# Objects & Methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object

What is the best way to make something like a class in JavaScript and create multiple instances of it?

I've tried the following:

```
function Test() {
    var currentState = -1;
    var stateArray = new Array();
}

Test.prototype.SetState = function(state) {
    this.currentState = state;

    stateArray.push(state);

    if (stateArray.length > 2) {
        stateArray.splice(0, 1);
    }
}

Test.prototype.GetState = function() {
    return this.currentState;
}

var Object1 = new Test();
var Object2 = new Test();

var EState = {
    ONE: 1,
    TWO: 2,
};

Object1.SetState(EState.ONE); //<< fails here
```

It works if I use it to create one object, but when I create multiple objects and use any of them get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What would cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is stateArray and currentState are private (local only to `Test()`) So when you try to do `stateArray.push` in this context `stateArray` is undefined and therefore does not have a function called push. one way to fix this is make them a property of Test using the `this` key word

```js
function Test() {
  this.currentState = -1;
  this.stateArray = new Array();
}

Test.prototype.SetState = function(state) {
  this.currentState = state;

  this.stateArray.push(state);

  if (this.stateArray.length > 2) {
    this.stateArray.splice(0, 1);
  }
}
Test.prototype.GetState = function() {
  return this.currentState;
}

var Object1 = new Test();
var Object2 = new Test();

var EState = {
  ONE: 1,
  TWO: 2,
};

Object1.SetState(EState.ONE);
console.log(Object1);
```

if you would like these to be private you could only return the publicly available functions from the constructor and keep the private data hidden

```js
function Test() {

  //private
  var currentState = -1;
  var stateArray = new Array();
  //public
  return {
    SetState: function(state) {
      currentState = state;
      stateArray.push(state);
      if (stateArray.length > 2) {
        stateArray.splice(0, 1);
      }
    },
    GetState: function() {
      return currentState;
    }
  }
}



var Object1 = new Test();
var Object2 = new Test();

var EState = {
  ONE: 1,
  TWO: 2,
};

Object1.SetState(EState.ONE);
Object2.SetState(EState.TWO);
console.log(Object1.GetState());
console.log(Object2.GetState());
```

Comment: Thank you for finding my typo.  I just deleted my other posting because no one needs this site polluted with a bunch of typo questions.  But I expressed gratitude to you by reading several of your other postings just now and adding +1 to those that deserved it in and of their own separate, independent merits.